# Ocelot gives 404 and warning UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError for all routes with no route defined

Tags: .net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

> tl;dr; WebApplication with Ocelot added gives an error for any url of
> itself (as in, that doesn't have a (re)route defined)

I'm trying out Ocelot for the first time. I'm successful in proxying to another host, but Ocelot blocks the server of rendering any page of its own (UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError)...

I have to stick with **.net core 3.1** so I'm using [Ocelot version 15.0.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ocelot/15.0.7)
(I also tried v16.0.1)

I have used the following very basic ocelot.json which, according to the [documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html), shouldn't do anything except getting Ocelot starting. *I read this as "your site should work as is withouth anything being proxied to another server"*

```
{
  "Routes": [

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
   
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:44310"
  }
}
```

In Startup I also added **AddOcelot()** to ConfigureServices and **UseOcelot().Wait()** to Configure

Unfortunately when I now go to https://localhost:44310 I no longer see my site but a 404 for EVERY page. In the output I find the following warning :

```
warn: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 8000001d-0006-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, 
      message: DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting pipeline errors. IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError 
      Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /, verb: GET.
```

I believe it's save to ignore the warning on the requestId (if I read the [documentation on requestId](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/requestid.html) correct). The UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError on the other hand does smell like it could be the issue... Is this the reason for the 404?

Just for the record, when I give a fallback route in the routes array to proxy ALL trafic to another server downstream, this works. So Ocelot DOES work. But why does Ocelot block the upstream server of rendering any page?

(The above example is without any route, but same happens when you give a route that only mathches some routes. The rerouted url than works, all others fail)